# Does anyone know a way to scramble the elements in a list?

Tags: python, random

```
thelist = ['a','b','c','d']
```

How I can to scramble them in Python?

Comment: I think the answer might be `random.shuffle`.  8-)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
>>> import random
>>> thelist = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
>>> random.shuffle(thelist)
>>> thelist
['d', 'a', 'c', 'b']
```

Your result will (hopefully!) vary.

Answer (score 17):

```
import random
random.shuffle(thelist)
```

Note, this shuffles the list in-place.

Answer (score 8):

Use the [`random.shuffle()`](http://docs.python.org/library/random.html#random.shuffle) function:

```
random.shuffle(thelist)
```

Answer (score 6):

Use the `shuffle` function from the `random` module:

```
>>> from random import shuffle
>>> thelist = ['a','b','c','d']
>>> shuffle(thelist)
>>> thelist
['c', 'a', 'b', 'd']
```

Comment: Hey, how come you got different output to Peter? ;)

Comment: Who else went straight to the 'Add Comment' button to lambast, before seeing the wink? :P

Answer (score 1):

**in-place** shuffle (modifies v, returns None)

```
random.shuffle(v)
```

**not in-place** shuffle (if you don't want to modify the original array, creates a shuffled copy)

```
v = random.sample(v, len(v))
```