# Scramble Python List

Tags: python, arrays, list, random, shuffle

Before I ask my question, let me get this straight...

This is not a duplicate of [Does anyone know a way to scramble the elements in a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1524160/does-anyone-know-a-way-to-scramble-the-elements-in-a-list) and [Shuffle an array with python, randomize array item order with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/473973/shuffle-an-array-with-python). I'll explain why...

I want to know how to scramble an array, and ***make a new copy***. Because `random.shuffle()` modifies the list in place (and returns `None`), I want to know if there is another way to do this so I can do `scrambled=scramblearray()`. If there isn't a built-in function, I could define a function to do this if possible.

Comment: What's wrong with making a new copy, then scrambling it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Shuffle an array with python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/473973/shuffle-an-array-with-python)

Comment: @Marcin Personally, I don't think that these answers could be merged with the answers on [Shuffle an array with Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/473973/shuffle-an-array-with-python)

Comment: Yes, they could. They happen to also demonstrate that you can copy an array. There is no reason why you couldn't have figured this out by yourself.

Comment: I think you should possible make a new copy of the array and scramble it using `random.shuffle()`. It works fine. If you don't like that way, you should probably explain clearly why you don't want. That will help us to understand.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
def scrambled(orig):
    dest = orig[:]
    random.shuffle(dest)
    return dest
```

and usage:

```
import random
a = range(10)
b = scrambled(a)
print a, b
```

output:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9] [6, 0, 2, 3, 1, 7, 8, 5, 4, 9]
```

Answer (score 12):

Use sorted(). It returns a new list and if you use a random number as key, it will be scrambled.

```
import random
a = range(10)
b = sorted(a, key = lambda x: random.random() )
print a, b
```

**Output**:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9] [5, 9, 0, 8, 7, 2, 6, 4, 1, 3]
```

Answer (score 3):

Copy the array *then* scramble it:

```
import random

array = range(10)   
newarr = array[:] # shallow copy should be fine for this
random.shuffle(newarr)
#return newarr if needs be.
zip(array, newarr) # just to show they're different

Out[163]:
[(0, 4),
 (1, 8),
 (2, 2),
 (3, 5),
 (4, 1),
 (5, 6),
 (6, 0),
 (7, 3),
 (8, 7),
 (9, 9)]
```